# Can heavily index table have its updates slower even if the columns updated aren't in any of the indexes?

Tags: database-performance, sap-ase

I'm trying to understand why a 14 Milion row table is so slow updating, even though I'm joining with its primary key, and updating in batches( 5000 rows).

**THIS IS THE QUERY**

```
UPDATE  A
SET     COL1= B.COL1,    
        COL2 = B.COL2,    
        COL3 = 'ALWAYS THE SAME VAL'    
FROM    TABLE_X A, TABLE_Y B    
WHERE   A.PK = B.PK
```

TABLE_X has 14 Million rows

TABLE_X has 12 INDEXES, however the updated columns do not belong to any index. so it's not expected that this slowness  is caused by having so many indexes right?

TABLE_Y has 5000 rows

**ADITIONAL INFORMATION**

I must update by the order of other column(Group) rather than the PK. If I could update by the order of PK then it would be way faster.
This is a business need. If they need to stop the process. they want groups to be either updated or not updated at all.

What could be causing such slow updates?

Database is SYBASE 15.7

Comment: Add to the question results from: set statistics io on, set statistics time on

Comment: the query plan would be helpful (eg, direct update? deferred update? poor join order? poor/wrong index selection?); also of importance ... any triggers firing on this table?  any referential integrity constraints being fired (should be noticeable in the query plan)? and, of course, please quantify 'slow'; at some point it would probably be good if you expanded on what you mean by updating by Group or PK,  and if tested, the differences in run times